# How can one log into Auth0 for integration testing?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, web-component, e2e-testing, auth0

I'm using [@web/test-runner](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) to perform e2e testing of a web application that uses Auth0. This has been a problem because Auth0 doesn't allow for wildcard path addition for redirects and @web/test-runner doesn't seem to allow different-origin navigation during test running. Does anyone know of a method of signing into Auth0 during integration/e2e testing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following article detailing a great method allowing login during e2e testing:
[Programmatic login to Auth0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication#Custom-Command-for-Auth0-Authentication). The article is written about Cypress but the same concepts can be used with a different test runner/framework. The only thing I was uncomfortable with was the need to include the Auth0 app secret. Using environment variables as well as a test application rather than the publicly available app makes me feel better.